# python imaging library draw text new line how to?

Tags: python-imaging-library

i have a word that will be putted on a image but the problem is that the word continues even though the word exceeds the width of the image

is there anyway that the word shift's down if the word exceeds the width of the image or on a certain point the word shift's down if it exceeds the given point

Comment: What code do you have so far? It is hard to tell what your problem is let alone correct it with so little information.

Comment: its like printing the letter on a new line

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/748453/writing-text-with-carriage-return-to-image-in-python-using-pil

Answer (score 6):

PIL won't automatically do this, but you could easily do it yourself using the `getsize` method in the `ImageFont` module.  That is, if the text is too big, just split it so that it's not, and put the rest on the next line.  (You may want to do this recursively in case the text spans multiple lines.)